# CruiseControl unable to recognize modifications for Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, continuous

I am trying to implement a continuous build stack, and decided to use CruiseControl with Ant. However, it seems that CruiseControl is having problem picking up the changes from my Mercurial directory. Here's some code from config.xml with a bunch of unnecessary elements taken out. One workaround I found was to set requiremodification to false, which will build the software regardless of the changes made. Am I missing something here? Or is this a bug of CruiseControl.

```
<!--config.xml-->
<project name="test_runner" buildafterfailed="false"
    requiremodification="true" forceonly="${test_runner.inactive}">
    <listeners>
        <currentbuildstatuslistener file="${projectLogsDir}/status.txt" />
    </listeners>

    <bootstrappers>
    </bootstrappers>

    <modificationset quietperiod="${quietPeriod}">

        <mercurial localworkingcopy="${mercurialDir}/solution1" property="solution1_changed" />

    </modificationset>

    <schedule interval="${scheduleInterval}">
        <ant liveOutput="true" />
    </schedule>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CruiseControl.Net the server logs which command it performs to check for changes. You can check if this command is correct by running it yourself on the command line. I had the same issue with Perforce, and by running the command myself I found out that I had configured an incorrect view.

Note that I'm much more familiar with CruiseControl.Net than CruiseControl, so this might not apply to CruiseControl.